# Start an Activity from DialogFragment in Android Xamarin Studio

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

How to start an activity from fragment in MonoAndroid (C#).

```
    var activity2 = new Intent (this, typeof(ImportScreen));
    activity2.PutExtra ("MyData", "Data from Activity1");
    StartActivity (activity2);
```

like this but xamarin outputs error:

> Error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'DialogScreen'
>   to 'Android.Content.Context' (CS1503)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mapo's answer is correct but just in wrong language format. Try this:

```
var activity2 = new Intent (this.Activity, typeof(ImportScreen));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try getActivity() instead this in Intent or getApplicationContext() from the getActivity()

Comment: not working ` The name 'getActivity' does not exist in the current context (CS0103) `